# How to size these resistors for the MOSFET gate or are they redundant for this case?

Tags: mosfet, solid-state-relay

I want to control [this solid state relay](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/140b/0900766b8140b509.pdf) through a 0/5V digital output. The digital output should not draw more than 10mA so I will use [this FET transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF). 12V DC power supply is used to switch the relay ON when the FET receives 5V to its gate. I have drawn the diagram as shown below:

[image]

Do I need R1 and/or R2 in this case? How can I verify that?
I was thinking R2 might help if the gate is floating but might be unnecessary.
I don't have much experience using discrete mosfets so I couldn't figure out if I need R1 or R2 at all.

edit:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 0/5V_IN is a push/pull output, then you don't need R2. R1 can be a very small value resistor, the datasheet test setup uses 25 ohm.

If your output is not push pull, then you would need a R2 resistor, that will dicharge the gate capacitance when turned off. Typically a 10k om would do the job.

EDIT:

R1 will determine how fast the MOSFET will start to conduct. If this is not critical, which in your case will just turn on a LED in the SSR, then enough large resitstor can be used. For example a peak current would be I=5V/R1. Using a 500 ohm you get 10mA peak current. This current is present at turn on, when gate cpacitance is discharged. Once the gate is charged no current flows. If you have to turn off, then you might need a discharge rsistor R2. Now you have toy pay attention, since they form a voltage divider you will get a gate voltage smaller thean 5V, so you have to use a ressitor with yet higher resistance. Or you can put the R2 resistor before the R2 in parallel to the output.

Let's say R1=470 and R2=47k as from your schematics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I might use Arduino(but it is not clear yet) but for some reason I dont wanna exceed 10mA. How can I verify whether its output is push pull?

Comment: It's generally good practice to put a high value R2 in anyway, just to ensure that the gate is always being driven to a known voltage. For many digital outputs, there will be times that they are high impedance and not-push pull (like the arudino when it's in reset)

Comment: @Marko Bursic Here is the edited version after reading your answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T57b6.png

Answer (score 1):

The demand for charge from the gate-driver (here your MCU) can be enormous, and your gate-driver should be sized for that charge or current requirement, or you risk losing control of the gate and having the FET go into oscillation or self-destruct.

There is a  plateau in turnon and in turnoff, where the drain-gate capacitance undergoes a large delta-voltage which requires a large **charge** from the gate-driver. The plateau occurs when the gate-driver cannot provide this large charge, demanded in what is labeled "miller capacity" charging. Here your drain voltage is only twice the gate voltage, thus your Miller Capacity charge demand will be 10X lower than if you were switching 120 volts with only a 5 volt gate-driver.

Read the datasheet on the SSR and look for information on charge required during switching, and look for the slowest switching time (10% to 90%) allowed. The charge will be Cgate * 5v + Cdrain-gate * 12 volts. Divide that charge by the time, and you have the current required; can your MCU provide that?

==========================================
[ question from OP]
Btw this is not a nonstop turn ON/OFF application at high frequency. This is just for DC static operation. Normally the MOSFET will be ON so the relay. And in case it will be OFF. Does it still matter?

[answer]
There is a Safe Operating Area spec for both bipolar and FET transistors, to be respected when switching, even if only switching ONCE. Some modern FETS are very delicate when switching, and JPL (the high-reliability satellite people) uncovered this problem, then found the car-manufacturers already knew of the self-destruction problem. Solution? Switch the FET faster than 1 microsecond. Ensure your charge source can supply the needed charge ( current * time) in less than one microsecond.

Comment: I dont know but I think probably I will use arduino uno. what do you think?

Comment: wouldn't 470 Ohm limit what you say?

Comment: Btw this is not a nonstop turn ON/OFF application at high frequency. This is just for DC static operation.  Normally the MOSFET will be ON so the relay. And in  case it will be OFF. Does it still matter?

Comment: There is a Safe Operating Area spec for both bipolar and FET transistors, to be respected when switching, even if only switching ONCE. Some modern FETS are very delicate when switching, and JPL (the high-reliability satellite people) uncovered this problem, then found the car-manufactures already knew of the self-destruction problem. Solution? Switch the FET faster than 1 microsecond. Ensure your charge source can supply the needed charge ( current * time) in less than one microsecond.

Comment: The SSR " Input Impedance" is given as "current regulator" 16mA for 5V. I dont understand what does that mean.

Comment: How about using a gate driver for the MOSFET?

Comment: Assuming the MCU output is push/pull, go ahead and use your values.

Comment: you mean no extra driver needed? thanks